# English query generation through machine translation systems

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, translation

I'm working on a project to generate questions from sentences. Right now, I'm at a point where I can generate questions like:
"Angela Merkel is the chancelor of Germany." -> "Angela Merkel is who?"

Now, of course, I want the questions to look like "Who is...?" instead. Is there any easy way to do this that I haven't thought of yet?

My current idea would be to train an English(not quite question) -> English(question) translator, maybe using existing machine translation engines like moses. Is this overkill? How much data would I need? Are there corpora that address this or a similar problem? Is using a general translation engine even appropriate for this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Michael Heilman's dissertation [Automatic Factual Question Generation from Text](http://www.ark.cs.cmu.edu/mheilman/questions/papers/heilman-question-generation-dissertation.pdf) for background on question generation and to see what his approach to this problem looks like.  You can find more by searching for research on "question generation".  He mentions a corpus from Microsoft: the [Microsoft Research Question-Answering Corpus](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/88c0021c-328a-4148-a158-a42d7331c6cf/).

I don't think that an approach based solely on (current) statistical machine translation approaches is going to work that well, since you're usually going to need a deeper syntactic analysis of the source sentence to do a good job of generating an appropriate question.  For simple questions like your example, it's pretty easy to design syntactic tree transformations to generate the question, but it gets much trickier as soon as the sentences get a little more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, if you restrict yourself to relatively simple questions, you could do a parse, and then flip around the elements to get the question. How do you decide the question word though? Who, What, Where, Why... for this you'll need a classifier that looks at the elements of a sentence. Angela Merkel should be easy to classify as a person/name, so she gets s 'Who', Berlin should be in a dictionary of geos, so it gets 'Where'.

I'm not sure about specific software, but I'd probably do it with NLTK, using a dependency parse and then whatever classification scheme you feel like.

Ultimately your success depends on how big your input and output space is. I'd go for the absolute simplest possible problem first.

Comment: right now, i just use Named Entitiy Recognition. Deciding on a question word for those named entities is pretty straight-forward.

Comment: that sounds good. have you tried using a translator to create the questions yet? a similar possibility might be to train the actual steps needed to take a dependency parse to the question form.

Comment: No, i haven't, since i would need an appropriate training set, which i don't have. Do you know references on how to do/train such transformations? As of now, i have only encountered binary and multiclass classification, your idea sounds a little more complicated. And even if i had an algorithm that could learn such transformations - where would i get training data from?

Comment: For what I'm thinking, you'd definitely need to construct your own training set. I don't have a reference on such transformations, but there's probably some linguistics literature about such things. Hmmmmm I'll think about it a bit.